# Getting ID from an item that's not saved yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am saving data to two different models at once. This has successfully been done.

These two models are associated with each other, so one most store the others ID on save. How to I store the questionnaire_contact_id in QuestionnaireResult?

```
class QuestionnaireResultsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @questionnaire_result = QuestionnaireResult.new(params[:questionnaire_result])
    @questionnaire_contact = QuestionnaireContact.new(params[:questionnaire_contact])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @questionnaire_result.save
        @questionnaire_contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Questionnaire was successfully submited.' }
        format.json { render json: questionnaires_path, status: :created, location: questionnaires_path }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: questionnaires_path.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use activerecord [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
def create
  @questionnaire_result = QuestionnaireResult.new(params[:questionnaire_result])
  @questionnaire_contact = @questionnaire_result.questionnaire_contacts.new(params[:questionnaire_contact])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @questionnaire_result.save #this line will automatically save associated contact
      # code
    else
      # code
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was as easy as doing this:

```
class QuestionnaireResultsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @questionnaire_result = QuestionnaireResult.new(params[:questionnaire_result])
    @questionnaire_contact = QuestionnaireContact.new(params[:questionnaire_contact])

    respond_to do |format|
      @questionnaire_contact.save
      @questionnaire_result.admin_questionnaire_contact_id = @questionnaire_contact.id
      if @questionnaire_result.save

        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Questionnaire was successfully submited.' }
        format.json { render json: questionnaires_path, status: :created, location: questionnaires_path }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: questionnaires_path.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```